# Using Gradle to build Python application

Tags: java, python, gradle, pyinstaller

I use Python, PyQt, MySQL and Pyinstaller to build stand alone exe applications.  I am very satisfied with the flexibility of this environment.  Today however, I manually run independent commands to do the following types of tasks:

1. Build .qrc resource files for all .qrc files in source path
2. Build .ui qt-designer files for all .ui files in source path
3. Build python exe using pyinstaller
4. Delete the generated files because they clutter the source directory and are no longer needed
5. Run my own custom script to build an installer for the pyinstaller generated exe

I would like to use Gradle as a build system for these tasks.  I realize Gradle is mostly used for Java projects, but I see no reason it can't be used for Python projects.

*Does anyone have a similar working example of a gradle.build file for the above tasks?  Or... provide help in creating one?*

Here are a few detailed examples of the above commands:

```
C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4/pyuic4.bat $file > ${file_base_name}_ui.py
C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4/pyrcc4.exe $file -o ${file_base_name}_rc.py
c:/python27/python.exe c:/pyinstaller/pyinstaller.py --onefile --noconsole --out=$file_path/$file
```

Comment: Why don't just write a simple bash script?

Comment: as of 2019, you might also consider https://github.com/linkedin/pygradle.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question! It may not help you explicitely with all your tasks but can give you an advice into the right direction.

Just have a look at the gradle [`Exec` task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html). With that you might be able to run the necessary python build steps within your gradle build, e.g.

```
task runpy(type:Exec) {
    workingDir './pydir'
    commandLine 'python', 'pyinstaller.py'
}
```